# Search the element by its name and also by its id in ng-select

Tags: angular

I am using ng-select for autocomplete input and its also working correctly, but i want to search the element by its name and also by its id.What should i do?

```
<label>Your first ng-select</label>
<ng-select [items]="SearchedData"
           bindLabel="CountryName"
           bindValue="PkCountryMaster"
           placeholder="Select Country"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
           (change)="Alert()">
</ng-select>
<p>
   {{selectedCountry | json}}
</p>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom search function. You can replace `name` and `id` with the actual property name within your Country object.

```
customSearch(term: string, item) {
  term = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
  return item['CountryName'].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || item['PkCountryMaster'].toString().indexOf(term) > -1;
}
```

And on your component.html, you can find the `customSearch` method to the `searchFn` input binding

```
<ng-select [items]="SearchedData"
           bindLabel="CountryName"
           bindValue="PkCountryMaster"
           placeholder="Select Country"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
           [searchFn]="customSearch"
           (change)="Alert()">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: What are the actual property names?

Comment: [{"SN":1,"PkCountryMaster":74,"CountryName":"Afghanistan"},{"SN":2,"PkCountryMaster":35,"CountryName":"Albania"},{"SN":3,"PkCountryMaster":50,"CountryName":"Algeria"},{"SN":4,"PkCountryMaster":20,"CountryName":"America"},

Comment: i want to search by PkCountryMaster and  CountryName

Comment: @Shweta Ah, okay, I didnt know `PkCountryMaster` is a number. I have edited my code.

Comment: Thank you so much,it is working perfectly. Thanx again.